# I am getting error message: "Unable to load the requested file". How to solve the problem?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```php
class Home extends CI_controller
{

    function index()

    {
        // $data['title'] = "iezant | index";
        $data['main'] = 'demo';
        $this->load->view('layout/main_view', $data);
    }
```

**Views/layout/main_view.php**

```php
<?php 

    $this->load->view($main);

?>
```

**Views/layout/demo.php**

```html
<h1> this is work </h1>
```

Url : http://localhost/arun/index.php/home/index/

Comment: Taking a total guess here but shouldn't it be `$data["main"] = "layout/demo";` if `demo.php` is also in the `layout` directory? It would really help if you included the actual error message

Answer (score 1):

In your controller :

```
$data['main'] = 'layout/demo';
//layout is your directory name
```